# Hosting a website with Rails, Groovy or Java servlets - shared hosting or VPS?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Are there hosting companies that cater for Rails, Groovy and Java servlets? Or is my only choice to use a VPS?

If so, how do I publish my website on the hosting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are hosting companies that offer that sort of technology. [This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) covers the things to look for when choosing hosting, so I'm not going to recommend a specific one. You may find that you they place limitations on what you can do or what modules you can install so it may be that you need a VPS. So you need to do your homework and ask the hosting companies about the specific things that you need. If they don't answer your questions at all or satisfactorily then you have to ask yourself whether they'd give you good support if you were a customer.

As to how you publish it, look at the support information for the hosting company that you choose.